# CNN's - visualizing maximized filter activation with Tensorflow (using MNIST)

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am currently working on creating visualizations for a maximal input image given the kernel/filters generated by a Convolutional Neural Network.

Keras had a blog post [here](https://blog.keras.io/how-convolutional-neural-networks-see-the-world.html) that does something similar, but the results were questionable at best when using anything but the supplied dataset, so I thought I might give it a try with Tensorflow directly. [I will try and edit my post later with the images from it, not available on this computer].

Using the MNIST dataset along with the Tensorflow tutorial and Keras blog post as reference, I have generated the following code in attempts to create said visualizations. I am not sure if my methodology is correct, especially with how/when to normalize my results to visualize them.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import copy
from scipy.misc import imsave


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ CNN ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#Most of the CNN section directly from the tutorial
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
img_width = 28
img_height = 28
n = 3
remove_negatives = False
normalize = True
use = 'layer'


def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return(tf.Variable(initial))

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return(tf.Variable(initial))

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   for i in range(5000):
     batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
     if i%100 == 0:
       train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
       print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
     train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
   layer = sess.run(W_conv1[:,:,:,:])
   bias = sess.run(b_conv1)
   layer2 = sess.run(W_conv2[:,:,:,:])
   bias2 = sess.run(b_conv2)





#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Begin Visualization Code ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
kept_filters = []
layer_use = layer
bias_use = bias
k=1
#toggle between layer 1 and layer 2 based on variable defined at beginning
if use != 'layer': 
   k = np.shape(layer2[:,:,:,:])[2]
   layer_use = layer2
   bias_use = bias2

#loop through kernels/feature maps and maximize each one's input image
for fmap in range(len(layer[0,0,0,:])):
   feat_map = fmap
   #randomized white-noise input image that will be max'ed
   noise_mat = weight_variable([1,28,28,k])
   #load kernel as a constant
   single_layer = tf.constant(layer_use[:,:,0:k,feat_map-1:feat_map] + bias_use[feat_map],dtype=tf.float32)
   conv = conv2d(noise_mat,single_layer)
   #Use mean of the image matrix as the "loss" - is this the proper way to do this?
   loss = -tf.reduce_mean(conv)
   train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.5).minimize(loss,var_list=[noise_mat])

   #the training/maximizing     
   with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      updatelist = [np.sum(sess.run(noise_mat)[0,:,:,0])]
      noise_mat_begin = sess.run(noise_mat[0,:,:,0])
      conv_saved = sess.run(conv)
      for __ in range(5000):
         train_step.run()
         if __%200 == 0:
            updatelist = updatelist + [np.sum(sess.run(noise_mat)[0,:,:,0])]
      noise_mat_end = sess.run(noise_mat)[0,:,:,0]     
   noise_mat_normed = copy.deepcopy(noise_mat_end)

   #not sure the best way to normalize?
   if remove_negatives:
      noise_mat_normed[noise_mat_normed <= 0] = 0   
   if normalize:
      std = np.std(noise_mat_normed)
      mean = np.mean(noise_mat_normed)
      def full_norm(val):
         return((val - mean)/std)
      vnew = np.vectorize(full_norm)
      noise_mat_normed = vnew(noise_mat_normed)
   else:
      oldmax = np.max(noise_mat_normed)
      oldmin = np.min(noise_mat_normed)
      def new_range(val,OldMax,OldMin):
         return((((val - OldMin) * 255) / (OldMax - OldMin)))
      vnew = np.vectorize(new_range)
      noise_mat_normed = vnew(noise_mat_normed,oldmax,oldmin)

   #negative sums generally imply a lack of convergence due to my loss metric, so remove them   
   if np.sum(noise_mat_normed) > 0:
      kept_filters += [noise_mat_normed]


#visualize results in a grid format, similar to the blog post
kept_filters = kept_filters[:n * n]
margin = 5
width = n * img_width + (n - 1) * margin
height = n * img_height + (n - 1) * margin
stitched_filters = np.zeros((width, height))

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        img = kept_filters[i * n + j]
        stitched_filters[(img_width + margin) * i: (img_width + margin) * i + img_width,
                         (img_height + margin) * j: (img_height + margin) * j + img_height] = img

imsave('TF_vis_%dx%d.png' % (n, n), stitched_filters)
```

This produces results like so (from convolutional layer 1):

[image]

I'm not sure if this is at all correct, especially since layer 2 doesn't seem much different. Do my results and/or methodology seem reasonable? Has anyone else done this using the MNIST dataset? As an aside, validation accuracy was >95%.

**EDIT**: I must have been doing something wrong originally; I re-did/re-ran the code from the blog post and now the results from my own Tensorflow code look about the same as the blog post method's output, so that's good. However, the main concerns still stand:

Why am I not getting more obvious or distinct outputs? I know they wont be as specific as the filters themselves, but these images don't seem to portray anything, unlike the blog post counterparts. Is there just not enough variation in the original dataset?

Shouldn't I be getting at least SOME things that aren't just glorified bordered images, like diagonals or curves?

Shouldn't the second layer look a more complex iteration of the first?